# Apache Camel : Polling the old files when I run as stand alone java project. Is there a way to poll only the new files

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a requirement to transfer the files from my local specific folder location to other location. I am using Apache Camel as a stand alone project and here is my code

```
from(file:<location>?noop=true).to(file:<location>)
```

Whenever I run as a Java project, It keeps on polling the old files as well which is moved on previous run. Is there a way to poll only the new files and also I am unable to log the file transfers

Example: 
On First run : source directory has

```
Folder1/image1
```

```
from(file:Folder1?noop=true).to(file:Folder2)
```

Will move the image1 to Folder2 location and image1 will remain in the Folder1.
Now I am going to run the java file again and I added one more file image2 to the source directory

```
FFolder1/image1 & image2
```

Now In this case I want only the image2 file to be processed, but the code process the image1 as well.

Comment: The `noop=true` option will ensure the files are not moved or reprocessed. Are these files getting updated elsewhere? This might explain why they keep getting polled again.

Comment: These files are not processed elsewhere . Each time I run the java file, I am observing that there is a change in the modified time for the files which is in the destination folder location

Comment: You could have the files moved to another location when the process runs so they disappear from the source location, using the option `move=<location>`

Comment: James updated question with my scenario

Comment: Try add `idempotent=true` as another option after `noop`. This should be done automatically by Camel whenever `noop` is set to true but maybe this is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since noop=true the file still remains in the source folder after the java process with camel routes is started. When you restart the java program it does not remember anything and hence polls all the files in source folder again. noop=true helps if the route is running continuously and not restarted.

You can avoid this by removing noop so the camel route moves the processed files from the source folder to a .camel folder or any folder you specify.

The solution depends on how you use it. If there is a strict requirement not to move files from the source folder then you need to remember it on the consumer side who consumes the destination folder, so you do not process the same files again or the route should not be restarted.